# How do I use amiibos?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf, amiibo, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I got an amiibo but I don't know how to use them in animal crossing new leaf. I haven't played it in a year (or a bit less), is there a new place or do I need to get something in the game to use the amiibos?

Note: I have a new 3ds xl

Answer (score 1):

I don't own the game myself, but failing any notice by Nintendo the update is available to download through the eShop.

Even once you get updated you need a *new* Nintendo 3DS to scan Amiibos directly, or their puck-shaped NFC reader accessory for older 3DS models.